# Spring multiple non overriding abstract methods found in interface

Tags: java, spring, microservices, feign

I'm facing some difficulties while trying to understand how to deal with feign client that extends an interface that has more than one method (end-point). This is a RestController of one of my microservices :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public interface ISPnetController {

    @GetMapping("/spnetQuery/summaryInfo/{hostname}")
    @ApiOperation(value="", nickname = "summaryInfo")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    SPSummaryResponseDTO getSPnetSummaryData(@PathVariable("hostname") String hostname);

    @PostMapping("/spnetQuery/historyInfo")
    @ApiOperation(value="", nickname = "historyInfo")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    SPHistoryResponseDTO getSPnetHistoryData(@RequestBody SPHistoryReqParams params);
}
```

Now, in my main service, I create a feign client which extends the controller of the previous service :

```
@FeignClient(name = "SPNETService")
public interface ISPnetServiceClient extends ISPnetController {
}
```

Now I need to implement the following bean, but I'm not sure how to do it :

```
@Configuration
@Development
public class AppDevConf {


    @Bean
    ISPnetServiceClient spnetServiceClient()
    {
        SPSummaryResponseDTO response = new SPSummaryResponseDTO();
        response.setSpnetRecordsList(ImmutableList.of(
            new SPSummaryInfoDTO("da1", "so1", "se1", "m1", "ec1", "du1","dw","ds"),
            new SPSummaryInfoDTO("da2", "so2", "se2", "m2", "ec2", "du2","s","ds")
        ));

        SPHistoryResponseDTO historyResponse = new SPHistoryResponseDTO();
        historyResponse.setSpnetHistoryRecordsList(ImmutableList.of(
            new SPHistoryDTO("da1", "so1", "se1", "m1", "ec1", "s",2),
            new SPHistoryDTO("da2", "so2", "se2", "m2", "ec2", "du2",2)
        ));

        return hostname -> response;
        return params -> historyReponse; //Of course I can't use return twice, but this is just to demonstrate what I would want to do, and I can't figure it out how to make it work.

    }
  }
```

It complains that : `"Spring multiple non overriding abstract methods found in interface ISPnetServiceClient"`

Comment: The problem is just what it says.  You haven't provided any implementations for the two methods in ISPnetController. - or maybe I don't understand the problem if those implementations should come from somewhere else.  I've never seen \@GetMapping and \@PostMapping applied to abstract methods before.